# Pgx OutOfMemoryError: maximum off-heap size is configured to not exceed 8,192 MBs

Tags: oracle, java-8, pgx

I'm having a problem with the [PGX API of Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oracle-labs/parallel-graph-analytix/overview/index.html).

I loaded a big graph and I apply successive filters, but after computing some calculations I destroy the temporaries graphs.

```
GraphChangeSet<Integer> subGraphChangeSet = 
currentSubGraph.createChangeSet();
    list.forEach(v -> subGraphChangeSet.updateVertex((Integer) v.getId())
            .setProperty("BLOCKED", true));

PgxGraph subGraphForRequest = subGraphChangeSet.build();

// ...

PgxGraph subGraphFiltered = subGraphForRequest
                .filter(new VertexFilter("vertex.BLOCKED == true"));

float edges = (float) subGraphFiltered.getNumEdges();

PgqlResultSet results = subGraphFiltered.queryPgql("SELECT label(e), COUNT(*) " +
                "MATCH () -[e]-> () GROUP BY label(e) ");

for (PgxResult result: results)
    map.put(property, (float) result.getLong(2) / edges);

subGraphFiltered.destroy();
subGraphForRequest.destroy();
```

But I'm having an `[ERROR] OutOfMemoryError: QUERY_PGQL failed maximum off-heap size is configured to not exceed 8,192 MBs.` exception when I try to perform the query.

So I tried to use the VM OPTS **-Xms512m -Xmx4g**, but PGX still ignoring those parameters. I even try **-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit** but nothing happened. I tried to modify the `pgx.conf` file in order to change the value of the `max_off_heap_size` parameter, but nothing happened either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more of research, I found in the doc that we're able to use system properties

> **System properties**
>
> Also, any PGX engine or runtime field can be set via Java system properties by writing -Dpgx.= arguments to the JVM PGX is running on. Note: Setting system properties will overwrite any other configuration. For example, to set the max off-heap size to 256GB, regardless of what another configurations says, use
>
> `java -Dpgx.max_off_heap_size=256000 ...`

[PGX Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56133_01/latest/reference/config/pgx.html)

This work for me.